# Changing default file permissions for files created by PHP

Tags: php, file-permissions

I have an Amazon EC2 server with multiple user accounts. Each user installs a PHP-based CMS system which during the install process downloads a few packages from a remote repository. The problem is that downloaded packages are not writable for the user (ei. cannot be deleted).

Question is, how can I set the default file permission for files created by PHP to 666?

Many thanks!

Comment: When you create a file with PHP, what user/group does the file have? Also, do you want this done via PHP or via the unix shell?

Comment: The files are created with owner apache:apache. I don't mind how its done, as long as it's a global setting that will work for every user. Let know if you have any ideas.

Comment: You can use `find` in unix to find all files, created by `apache` within a certain directory and apply `chmod 666` to all of them recursively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` to find all of the files that are owned by apache and then `chmod` them with the desired permissions.

For example:
`find <your direcoty path> -type f -user "apache" -exec chmod 666 {} \;`
will change the permissions of all files owned by `apache` in the specified path recursively.

While I was searching the web I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory), which I think, is a more proper way to handle your problem.